# Android. View элементы меняют дефолтный стиль в зависимости от типа Activity. Как установить единый стиль?

Tags: java, android, view, checkbox

Заметил что при создании различных типов Activity при создании приложения, к ним прикручиваются разные стили для чекбоксов и спиннеров, при создании Активити типа диалог там и вовсе свой стиль у элементов. Где эти стили прописываются в коде и как их на всех типах активити одинаковыми сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стили указываются в манифесте при объявлении активити с помощью атрибута ***android:theme***

В данном манифесте они указаны в теге ***application*** и в каждом теге ***activity***.

В атрибутах указаны ссылки на ресурс ***styles***

Если в теге ***activity*** не указан атрибут ***android:theme***, то берётся родительское значение этого атрибута (т.е. значение android:theme тега application)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stackoverflow.ru">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ScrollingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TagsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tags"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.GalleryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Сами описания стилей хранятся в ресурсах (/res/values/styles.xml например)

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Основная тема приложения наследуется от темы ***Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*** с помощью атрибута ***parent***

Внутри тега ***style*** переопределяются свойства темы

**Подробнее о стилях и темах читайте в руководстве:**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

---

Также тему Вы можете выбрать с помощью графического интерфейса в Android Studio.

Для этого Перейдите к редактированию активити и выберите вкладку ***Design***.

В панели сверху будет кнопка для выбора темы(*обведена красным маркеорм на изображении*)

При клике на неё появится окно выбора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]